# Using NSpopover in swift. How to change top bar

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspopover

I am using this code to show the VC when someone clicks on the preference pane.

```
let popover = NSPopover()
    popover.contentViewController = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("AuthVC") as? NSViewController
    popover.animates = true
    popover.behavior = NSPopoverBehavior.Transient
```

When the view shows up, the top bar is a standard bar. I want it to be like this with an arrow:

[image]

When I use this code:  `popover.showRelativeToRect(CGRectNull, ofView: ViewController , preferredEdge: NSRectEdge)` In ofView It wants an NSView However mine is a ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `-showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:` and pass an empty rect and the view in the menu to get the anchor (arrow).

Comment: I am using a View controller.

Comment: `NSPopOver` is not a view!? You can use a view controller for the content view. As I saw in your code, you know that …

Comment: As said: Pass the view in the menu, not your view controller.